# Swift Dictionary Build error

Tags: dictionary, compiler-errors, swift, ios8

I tried to do translate this obj-c code to swift code:

```
NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                              nil];
```

// swift

```
    var settings = [NSNumber.numberWithFloat(Float(44100.0)): AVSampleRateKey,
            NSNumber.numberWithInt(Int32(kAudioFormatAppleLossless)): AVFormatIDKey,
            NSNumber.numberWithInt(2): AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
            NSNumber.numberWithInt(Int32(AVAudioQuality.Max)): AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];
```

But I get the error: Type () does not conform to protocol 'FloatLiteralConvertible'

Does anybody know how to correct this? THX

Comment: The error message is misleading, use  **NSNumber.numberWithInt(Int32(AVAudioQuality.Max.toRaw()))**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several errors in your Swift code.

- The order of keys and values is wrong. In `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys`, the values
  precede the keys. But a Swift dictionary is written as

  ```
  [ key1 : value1, key2 : value2, ... ]
  ```
- The `NSNumber` initializers are mapped to Swift as

  ```
  NSNumber(float: ...), NSNumber(int: ...)
  ```
- `AVAudioQuality.Max` is an `enum`. To get the underlying integer value, you have
  to use `.rawValue`.

This gives

```
var settings = [AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber(float: Float(44100.0)),
    AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(kAudioFormatAppleLossless)),
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey : NSNumber(int: 2),
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue))];
```

But numbers are automatically wrapped into `NSNumber` objects if necessary,
so you can simplify that to

```
var settings : [NSString : NSNumber ] = [AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0,
    AVFormatIDKey : kAudioFormatAppleLossless,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 2,
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue];
```

In **Swift 2,** the type of `kAudioFormatAppleLossless` changed to `Int32` which is *not* bridged to `NSNumber` automatically, so you 
have to change this to

```
var settings : [NSString : NSNumber ] = [AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0,
    AVFormatIDKey : Int(kAudioFormatAppleLossless),
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 2,
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue];
```

Comment: Ah thank YOU :) I'll try it tomorrow and mark your answer then!

Comment: Great thanks! simple solution! The only thing I had to change was the AVFormatIDKey and used your first solution `AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(kAudioFormatAppleLossless))`

Comment: @GerritPost: You are welcome. The type of kAudioFormatAppleLossless changed in Swift 2, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32509565/how-to-resolve-type-of-expression-is-ambiguous-without-more-context-for-an-audio.