# How to resolve Type of expression is ambiguous without more context for an audio recorder in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9

I have upgraded to Swift 2.0 and I quite can't understand this when I try to record a sound:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

on `var recordSettings`

**What should I do to fixt this error and more important, why?**

```
 var recordSettings = [
        AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatAppleLossless,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue,
        AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
        AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0
    ]

    var dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    var docsDir: AnyObject = dirPaths[0]
    var soundFilePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("tempRecordzz")
    var soundFileURL:NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: soundFilePath)



    var error: NSError?
    do {
        recorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: soundFileURL, settings: recordSettings)
    } catch var error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
        recorder = nil
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The type of `kAudioFormatAppleLossless` changed from `Int` (Swift 1.2/Xcode 6.4) to `Int32` (Swift 2/Xcode 7) and `UInt32` in Swift 7.0.1. The *fixed sized* integer types
like `Int32` and `UInt32` are *not* automatically bridged to `NSNumber` objects
for insertion in an `NSDictionary`.

An explicit conversion helps to resolve the issue:

```
let recordSettings = [
    AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatAppleLossless), // <-- HERE
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue,
    AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
    AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0
]
```

Comment: `kAudioFormatAppleLossless` is `UInt32` as of Xcode7.0.1.